# Problem with download file on mobile devices

Tags: php

why when i try save xlsx file from mobile sites thats return me filename.xlsx.html, but on desktop this work fine

```
$xlsSave = new Xls($spreadsheet);

header('ContentType:application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.xlsx"');

$xlsSave->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Maybe any cache? Trehe is no reason for '.html'.